# How do I find the Rails module path for a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, introspection

New to ruby/rails. In a big Rails app, I come across methods and can't find the documentation for them. For example, there is a method `process`. When I introspect and examine its ancestors, I can get to  `Rails::Controller::Testing::TemplateAssertions.process` but googling that doesn't give me any documentation about how to use the method, just the [method's definition](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/rails-controller-testing/Rails/Controller/Testing/TemplateAssertions) which is very obscure.

What I wanted to find was `ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.process` which I can then look up in https://api.rubyonrails.org/ and get verbose documentation on how to use the method. I think I have trouble finding this "original" module path because of Rails's use of mixins. The only way I found it was by sifting through files and files of the rails repository before I found it mentioned in some comment. So my question is, is there a more deterministic way to find the origin of a method?

EDIT: the context of this code looks kind of like this:

```
require 'test_helper'
class C < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
   include OtherHelper
   ...
   process(argA,argB,argC)
end
```

Comment: If `obj` responds to the method `m` have you tried `obj.method(:m).owner`?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. What is `obj` in this case? I tried `method(:m).owner` but that's what gets me `Rails::Controller::Testing::TemplateAssertions`

Comment: Is `process` is an instance method (i.e., to be `include`d in a class) or a module method, in which case it is executed by it's fully-qualified module name (e.g., `M1::M2:M3.process(...)`)? If the former (which seems unlikely given its very common name) and you knew it was an instance method of some class `C`, it's location would be given by `C.instance_method(:process).owner` (or `c.method(:process), where `c` is any instance of `C`). For example, `Array.instance_method(:puts).owner #=> Kernel`.  Why do you need the class? Suppose the method were `size`. Many classes have a method `size`.

Comment: `process` is in fact an instance method, included at some point along the chain of inheritance, and it is not clear to me which class it is really coming from (perhaps this is the question I should be asking). When I execute `C.instance_method(:process).owner`, I get the same result as when I run `method(:process).owner`, that is, `Rails::Controller::Testing::TemplateAssertions`

Comment: Try to find a class `C` (not literally "C") such that `C.instance_methods.include?(:process) #=> true`. Then (with `C` representing that class), `C.instance_methods(:process).owner`. You might also with to execute `C.instance_methods(:process).source_location`. See [Method#owner](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Method.html#method-i-owner) and [Method#source_location](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Method.html#method-i-source_location.

Comment: I did actually use the class that contains the call to `process`, not literally C. I'll update the question to show what the context looks like.

Comment: @CarySwoveland see updated description please

Comment: As you have defined it, `process` is a method of `C` (from some class or module) not an instance method of `C`. (Note `self #=> C` when `process` is executed.) So try `C.method(:process).owner`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland calling C.method on it gives an undefined method exception, as it is in fact an instance method.

Comment: @jvillian There is documentation for it when searched as ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.process

Comment: If `class C < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest; include OtherHelper; ...; process(argA,argB,argC); end` executes without error (after replacing `...` with code, naturally), then `C.method(:process).owner` must return a value. Of course, if that subclass definition raises an exception all bets are off.

Comment: hmm @CarySwoveland it is clear your understanding of ruby is far superior to mine, but i can only relay what im seeing here, so maybe my simplified version was too simple. The code runs fine, and C.instance_method works while C.method gets an exception. To give some more context on the "..." This is within a Capybara minitest. So the ... consists of a capybara `it` block wrapped by a `context` block. But other than that it really does look the way Ive simplified it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple things you can use to help with introspection & debugging:

- Installing & requiring `pry`, `pry-byebug` and placing a `binding.pry` somewhere in the code will allow you to `step`/`next` thru the logic until you get to where you think you need to be
- Using the `owner` method as noted in the comment to your post. If you have a `User` model, you can, for example, from a console type `User.method(:_update_callbacks).owner` and see that it's from `ActiveRecord::Base`
- You can use the `.source_location` method to see which file something is defined in. For example, from a rails console I can type `User.method(:_update_callbacks).source_location` and see that method is defined on line 819 of the `active_support/callbacks.rb` file (with the full path noted in the response)
- If you knew that the module was being included, but weren't able to figure out where you could also edit the gem on your local system to print where it's being included

The below prints out `Bar`

```
module Foo
  def self.included(base)
    puts "including..."
    puts base
    puts "included..."
  end
end

class Bar
  include Foo
end
```

There's probably something better/cleaner out there but these might be useful.

More detail on using pry, per my comment below:

Given that I've run `gem install pry pry-byebug` and have the following code sample:

```
require 'pry'
require 'pry-byebug'

module Foo
  def blah
    puts "in Foo"
  end
end

class Bar
  include Foo

  def blah
    binding.pry
    super
    puts "in Bar"
  end
end

x = Bar.new
x.blah
```

When you hit the `binding.pry`, before the `super`, you can call `next` and that will step you into the new file where you can see file name and line number. You'll need to add the `binding.pry` in the actual gem file on your machine. `bundle open <gemname>` or `gem open <gemname>` should open the actual folder in your editor, and as long as you've got pry/byebug configured in your Gemfile (if using bundler) or install via `gem`, it should work.

[image: step with pry]

Comment: I upvoted your answer because I think this info complements the question. However I have tried these methods: `.owner` gives me the Rails::Controller::Testing::TemplateAssertions module path. `.source_location` gives me the file but that file just has the plain method definition which is very obscure and identical to what i find when seeing the definition in Rails::Controller::Testing::TemplateAssertions.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I just wanted to provide some debugging & introspection tools. If I could describe how I know that `super` here https://github.com/rails/rails-controller-testing/blob/master/lib/rails/controller/testing/template_assertions.rb#L61, is calling `ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.process` would that answer your question?

Comment: yes i think it would! if you could show me how i could go from seeing 'super' to finding who has the super definition

Comment: I added some more info on debugging with pry. There's def some downsides (if multiple things include the module, it might get hit multiple times before you find the caller you need). There's also some Kernel methods that might be useful: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Kernel.html#method-i-caller

Comment: There's a good example of using `caller` here, and other debug goodies too: https://www.schneems.com/2016/01/25/ruby-debugging-magic-cheat-sheet.html. This (from schneems site) is probably more useful than anything else I've posted: `puts method(:foo).super_method.source_location`

Comment: I think im still missing a step. So i've found the gem file (rack-test) by stepping into super. That brought me into a method with a different name `process_request` . I can place another pry in that file, but i'm still not sure how i get from the gem file to ActionDispatch::Integration::Session. In the gem I do find that i'm in a class `Session` so perhaps i'm one step closer. But it is not evident to me by looking at the gem file that Session is part of `ActionDispatch::Integration`

Comment: It wasn't super clear to me that the two pieces of code in your question were related either; I didn't see any includes or anything when I briefly looked thru the code. You can use step to keep stepping thru the code, rather than adding another pry. Next will step you over a method, step goes into iirc. If you can describe what you're testing I might try and replicate. Is this a standard rails 5 app, with rails controller testing gem? Request spec?

Comment: Also, the steps I'm showing will show you where super goes, not what calls the process method in the first place (just which modules and classes handle it)